# Using the Command Prompt to identify workspaces/datasets/dataflows/reports etc in PowerBI (or any other method)

Tags: powerbi, command-prompt

I have access to a shared PowerBI environment which consists of several different workspaces, which contain multiple reports/dashboards etc.

Is there a way to easily get a list of all of the above (need to have) and how each thing is linked (nice to have)?

A colleague mentioned there may be a way of completing this via the command prompt, but doesn't know how to do it himself.

I'm happy to use any other method to get the required information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have premission then you can try with powershell (rest-api)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

You can loop through workspaces/datasets and get all info